# CSS two column mode, prevents click on button with clip-path?

Tags: html, css

On our side we have a collection of 'cards', which have an href presented as a button using a clip-path, to make it non-rectangular. This works fine, but as soon as we change the parent container to be two column we can no longer click on the link.

Disabling the clip-path or the two-column mode allows the link to be clickable, but we are looking to have the combined effect work.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  column-count: 2;
}

ul>li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card {
  border: solid 1px gray;
  width: 300px;
  height: 220px
}

.abtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
  line-height: 6.9rem;
  background-color: rgb(19, 92, 189);
  width: 16rem;
  height: 8rem;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(2% 42%, 100% -5%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 46%);
  clip-path: polygon(2% 42%, 100% -5%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 46%);
  float: right;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li><div class="card"><a class="abtn" href="#">Click Me</a></div></li>
  <li><div class="card"><a class="abtn" href="#">Click Me</a></div></li>
  <li><div class="card"><a class="abtn" href="#">Click Me</a></div></li>
  <li><div class="card"><a class="abtn" href="#">Click Me</a></div></li>
  <li><div class="card"><a class="abtn" href="#">Click Me</a></div></li>
  <li><div class="card"><a class="abtn" href="#">Click Me</a></div></li>

</ul>
```

I have tested this in Chrome and Safari on macOS, where I see this behaviour. It works as expect in Firefox.

Code in context: https://jsfiddle.net/045q82ve/2/

The odd thing is it partially works in the JSFiddle where my sample wasn't working in a standalone HTML page. I say partially, since only the first button seems to be behaving as expected. Example works properly in Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the background  and the `clip-path` to am absolutely positioned pseudo element (`::before`), and place it under the link using `z-index: -1`:

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  column-count: 2;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

ul>li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card {
  border: solid 1px gray;
  width: 300px;
  height: 220px;
  text-align: right;
}

.abtn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: .7rem;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
  line-height: 6.9rem;
  width: 16rem;
  height: 8rem;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all .3s;
  text-align: center;
}

.abtn::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(2% 42%, 100% -5%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 46%);
  clip-path: polygon(2% 42%, 100% -5%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 46%);
  background: rgb(19, 92, 189);
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><div class="card"><a class="abtn" href="#">Click Me</a></div></li>
  <li><div class="card"><a class="abtn" href="#">Click Me</a></div></li>
  <li><div class="card"><a class="abtn" href="#">Click Me</a></div></li>
  <li><div class="card"><a class="abtn" href="#">Click Me</a></div></li>
  <li><div class="card"><a class="abtn" href="#">Click Me</a></div></li>
  <li><div class="card"><a class="abtn" href="#">Click Me</a></div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with this, I have filed a Chromium [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1139011&q=clip-path&can=2) which you can track.

I was able to solve this by creating my own click handler. Broadly this meant listening for a click event on the parent container (styled with `column-count`) and then iterating through all of the clipped elements inside the container and storing their bounding rectangles.

Thereafter I simply triggered the appropriate click event by checking if the location of the mouse pointer was inside the relevant bounding box.